# Print to console values between to integers infinitely in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout, infinite-loop

I would like to console.log values between 1 and 5 infinitely with a small delay of few seconds using JavaScript. I am trying to run the following code, but it stops after printing 1.

```js
    var z = 0
    setTimeout(function() { 
      if (z==6) {z=0};
        z+=1;
        console.log(z);
    }, 2000);
```

Is it possible to implement this using `setTimeout` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for setInterval:

```js
var z=0; 
setInterval(function() { 
  if (z==6) {z=0};
  z+=1;
  console.log(z);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() just performs the function once. you need use setInterval().:

```
var z=0; 
setInterval(function() { 
if (z==6) {z=0};
z+=1;
console.log(z);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential solution.  It's not implemented "infinitely" so the browser doesn't die, but you could increase i to your liking I suppose.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i % 5 + 1);
  }, 2000 * i);
}
```

Comment: Same as @Alexander's answer- this is blocking, and is problematic.